# Why is $a\cong b$ in this problem?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I am trying to understand the following problem: State the basic angle theorem needed to prove $a\cong b$ in the following figure:

> [image]

The answer is: Since $\overline{AB} \perp \overline{BC}$, $B$ is a right angle and hence, $b$ is the complement of $1$. Since $a$ is complement of $1$, $a\cong b$. Ie: Complements of the same angle are congruent.

I don't understand how $b$ being complement to $1$ forces it to be congruent to $a$.

Comment: @Blue Sorry, I mixed up the concepts in my mind.

Comment: The given solution states the key result: *"Complements of the same angle are congruent."* After all, algebraically, if $\angle a$ and $\angle 1$ are complements, the $\angle a+\angle 1=90^\circ$; likewise, $\angle b+\angle 1=90^\circ$; therefore, $\angle a+\angle 1=\angle b+\angle 1$, and we can subtract $\angle 1$ from both sides.

Comment: BTW: Are there multiple users on this account? The question here is quite a departure from others asked under this name.

Comment: @Blue No. I am an undergraduate student of mathematics in a university and always had a personal project of learning Euclidean geometry but never quite found the time nor the right material. I just found a book about it now and am (finally) learning it! I plan to also read Altschiller-Court's College Geometry and Johnson's Advanced Euclidean Geometry as soon as I finish this one. :-)

Comment: @RedBanana You have a question about algebraic geometry and somehow you are just now learning Euclidean geometry. That doesn't add up.  Seems there are multiple people using this account.

Comment: @oliverjones I guess you're making an unreasonable interpretation of what I just said: By *"I am learning Euclidean geometry"* I don't mean I don't know what a "circle" is, what "perpendicular" means, what "parallel" means, nor that I don't even know what "geometry" is. I meant that **I am learning about all the other stuff I didn't learn before in Euclidean geometry.** Geometric constructions, SSS, SAS, ASA theorems, etc. Obviously - as you noted - I knew enough geometry to pass a basic course in algebraic curves I did last semester.

Comment: You said you are "finally" learning it. Based on previous questions you've asked, it is puzzling that you would not understand $a \simeq b$ having already had so much mathematical experience. Your account is 10 years old, you asked about Pythagorean triples 8 years okay. To me, it seems as though there is more than one person using your account.

Comment: @oliverjones As you are American and you guys fail to perceive there could be other educational contexts in other places, I'll explain for you: I never learned basic geometry in school, at university, we learn "geometry with vectors" and we do stuff like: Given two vectors, compute the angle between them, find out (computing the dot product) if they are perpendicular, etc. Everything is "concrete" in the sense that a simple computation must be made so that I can check if something is true. This skill of reasoning through a diagram given only some properties is unknown to me and I got confused.

Comment: You are making assumptions about my nationality given my listed location. Furthermore, nothing I said indicates as though I have a narrow vision of what education can be. It is not unreasonable to be puzzled as to why someone with some advanced mathematical knowledge would be puzzled by congruent angles. I will not be replying further.

Comment: @oliverjones Now you're lying: You're not _"puzzled as to why someone with some advanced mathematical knowledge would be puzzled by congruent angles"_ you **made a direct accusation to me.** You could at least be honest.

Comment: I guess I lied in that I said I wouldn't reply. Yeah I am puzzled hence why I said it seems there are multiple people using your account. Also to be clear I surmised there is multiple people that could be using your account. I never directly said multiple people are using your account.  Now, I would like to end this. Good luck with your studies.